# Font Awesome failing to load

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to use font awesome. I have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.2.0/css/fontawesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-z4tVnCr80ZcL0iufVdGQSUzNvJsKjEtqYZjiQrrYKlpGow+btDHDfQWkFjoaz/Zr" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

in the head tag, but when I use this:

`<i class="fa-regular fa-user-hair"></i>`

, it fails, and just doesn't load anything.

Comment: Look t the console log in your browser devtools.

Comment: Yes, there are no issues

Comment: You are using a free version and that icon does not exist. Open the URL ```https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.2.0/css/fontawesome.min.css``` and check if  ```fa-user-hair``` exists in that file.

Comment: I realised that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not a free icon, pro is required

Answer (score 1):

2 reasons:

1. It could be that the icon you are trying to use is from a different version of Fontawesome. Your href is using version "6.2.0" so make sure that when you are referencing your icon in your HTML "" tag that the icon class name is a 6.2.0 version icon.

You can also copy the href URL ("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.2.0/css/fontawesome.min.css) and open it in your browser and search for the class name using CTRL+F. You can also use this to study how Fontawesome has coded their rules for their CSS styling.

||     OR

2. Your href is also referencing from the Free icons, and the class name you are trying to use is from the Pro version.

Comment: I literally just saw you answered your own question and determined it was because it was not in the list of class names in the free icons. lol